# Calling JQuery widget function from form.submit

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-widgets

I trying to invoke a public method of my jquery widget api from a form.submit but I'm having no success. Can anyone help me?

```
_cleanFormFields: function() {
  console.log("ok");
},

_addFormListener: function(map, marker) {
    var form = $(".add-form").clone().show();
    form.submit(function (event){
       event.preventDefault();
       _cleanFormFields();
    }
}
```

Why this does not work?? The browser's console raises "Uncaught ReferenceError: _cleanFormFields is not defined" exception

Comment: doesn't plugin have callbacks you can access from options? Or events you can bind to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_cleanFormFields` is a property of some object, right? So you can't call it directly, you need to reference it via your object:

```
yourObject._cleanFormFields();
```

Or, depending on how `_addFormListener()` is invoked you might be able to use `this`. But you'd need to keep a reference of the `this` from `_addFormListener()` because within the `.submit()` callback `this` will be the form element in question:

```
_addFormListener: function(map, marker) {
    var form = $(".add-form").clone().show(),
        self = this;
    form.submit(function (event){
       event.preventDefault();
       self._cleanFormFields();
    }
}
```

Comment: OW!! It worked like a charm! _cleanFormFields is a method from my widget. I thought that I could invoke it from any place of it. Thank you! Hey, could you post any good tutorial for helping me to learn more JQuery as widgets?

Comment: I don't have any widget tutorials to hand, but http://jquery.com has links to tutorials, and [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript) is a pretty good JavaScript reference. Note that the issue you had here is nothing to do with jQuery, it is a general JavaScript thing. If you use a constructor function rather than an object literal you can set things up so that your widget's methods can call each other directly, but in my opinion that is beyond the scope of this question.